# Change mouse cursor on external button click in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application need to change the default mouse cursor from hand to plus when I click on an external button. How do I do that?

Right now with the below code, it is always +. But I need to change the change the cursor only when I click on the button.

```js
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (e) {
                map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'crosshair' });
            });
```

```html
<div class="tool" id="toolbar" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 320px;">
    <img id="button" class="tool" src="~/Images/ruler.png" alt="Chnage Tool">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this with CSS. The button can toggle a class on the body (like `show-crosshair`) and then this will be your CSS:

```
.show-crosshair .your-map-container-class .gm-style > div {
  cursor: crosshair !important; 
}
```